# Exception while accessing HTTPSReceiverServlet

Tags: 2011, content-delivery

I was trying to configure UGC on the deployer service, but had to revert back. However, now I get the below exception when I try to access the URL: //websitelink/httpupload.

I checked the license and it had a valid period. I haven't modified anything except add additional JARs for UGC. I reverted all the configuration XML files back. I have googled this exception, but I don't see any working solution.

Thanks

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet httpupload threw exception
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>       org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>       org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
>       org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>   root cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory
>       com.tridion.transport.HTTPSReceiverServlet.init(HTTPSReceiverServlet.java:86)
>       org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>       org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>       org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
>       org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

### update

I am trying to configure the same content delivery jsp application with following server roles on the same jsp web application - content deployer, HTTP upload, content delivery web service and later on I will add UGC. When I try to access `http://deployer/httpupload` I get 404 error

### update

Ok so based on the feedback by Nickoli
I will keep the deployer as a seperate jsp app. Configure two separate Odata apps with ADF enabled and on separate JVM, and my JSP website on a separate JVM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error in your stacktrace

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory
```

is indicative of there being something wrong with your cd_storage_conf.xml or the values/properties specified within.  Check your that your cd_storage_conf.xml is valid and has correct values.

Also, if you update your question with the web.xml and the cd_storage_conf we can take a closer look.  Note, the web.xml file does specify the URL filter pattern for the servlet, so there may be an issue there in regards to the 404 you're seeing; and the cd_storage_conf may still have remnants of the UGC configs (did you fully comment them out?).

Comment: Deployer - no ADF and separate app on separate JVM, Odata - separate app on its own JVM and may have ADF, JSP app - separate app on separate JVM.  Please consider asking a new question, or moving this to Chat.

Comment: @user858 if you have updates please edit your original question and place the updates in there rather than continuing here in the comments. Comments are just for a single comment on the answer given, NOT to continue asking new or different questions. After you have updated your original question with all the info from the comments here, please delete your comments to keep this clean and readable.

Answer (score 2):

Tridion ships with XML schemas for all the content delivery configuration files. Validating the files against the schemas should be a big help in finding what's wrong.